# Test if each element contains an element with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I want to test if each of the elements `.elem1` contain an element `.elem2`. Tried this but doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
expect(element.all(by.css('.elem1')).all(by.css('.elem2')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you compare the number of `elem1` elements with the number of `elem1` elements having `elem2` elements inside:

```
var elem1count = element.all(by.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'elem1')]")).count();
var elem1WithElem2count = element.all(by.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'elem1') and .//*[contains(@class, 'elem2')]]")).count();
elem1WithElem2count.then(function (elem1WithElem2count) {
    expect(elem1count).toEqual(elem1WithElem2count);
});
```

Yeah, that was kind of ugly.

Similar idea, but using [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var elem1count = element.all(by.css(".elem1")).count();
var elem1WithElem2count = element.all(by.css(".elem1")).filter(function (elem1) {
    return elem1.element(by.css('.elem2')).isPresent();
}).count();

elem1WithElem2count.then(function (elem1WithElem2count) {
    expect(elem1count).toEqual(elem1WithElem2count);
});
```

---

Or, you can solve it with [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce):

```
var result = element.all(by.css('.elem1')).reduce(function(acc, elem1) {
    return elem1.element(by.css('.elem2')).isPresent().then(function (isPresent) {
        return acc && isPresent;
    });
}, false);
expect(result).toBe(true);
```

Here, for each `elem1` element we are getting a boolean variable indicating whether an `elem2` element is present or not and then reducing all of the booleans into a single boolean.

You may also use [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) and have an `expect` check for every `elem1`:

```
element.all(by.css('.elem1')).each(function(elem1) {
    expect(elem1.element(by.css('.elem2')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```